# i need a loop with a conditional? bash

Tags: bash, loops

I have this due and I have been stuck for hours, can somebody help?
I want this to loop if they choose IOU, the options were given already, otherwise say "thank you". also, after the second IOU i want it to break.
please and thank you

```
#! /bin/bash

payment(){

        read -a coin -p "how would you like to pay? "
        
        while [ "$coin" == "IOU" ]    
        do
           echo "excuse me?"
        if   
           [ "$coin" != "IOU" ]; then 
           echo "thank you"
           ((c++)) && ((c==2)) && break
        fi
        done
}
payment
```

Comment: Can you format your code correctly and tell us what language it is. Looks like bash but …

Comment: yes it is bash, I'm not sure how to fix it. i added the shebang

Answer (score 1):

To enter the while loop you need

```
[ "$coin" == "IOU" ]
```

then inside the loop it will never be

```
[ "$coin" != "IOU" ]
```